# WCF Channel "timed out" when sending lots of data

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a "self-hosted" WCF server, running as a console application. Connecting to this is a ASP.Net website, that pulls data from the WCF service on-demand - I ask the service for `x` records and they're returned to me.

This has been working fine for years, but recently we've seen it fail when trying to pull a large amount of data over the channel - I'm not talking gigabytes or anything: it's a fairly simple `List<T>` of objects. The exception thrown is:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or
>   increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

It's definitely not a timeout - the exception is thrown straight away.  I've narrowed it down to a size issue: if I ask for a bit less data, it works fine - so 50 records is fine but 51 throws the exception, which I'm sure means something is hitting a limit somewhere.

On the server side, I can see the request being received and sent back to the client. There's no exceptions being raised anywhere that I can see.

On both the client and the server, I'm using a fairly simple `WSHttpBinding`. I've set all the "Max" values to ridiculously big numbers - I know this isn't best practice, but the service is internal-only and I can tune it back down later.

The binding is:

```
 WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding
            {
                Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue,
                    MaxDepth = 32
                }
            };
```

and within the `web.config` I have:

```
maxRequestLength="40971520"
```

under `system.web`.

Can anyone suggest what's causing the "timeout" error to appear, and more importantly how to resolve it?

Comment: Show your configutaion file

Comment: mat be you forget to use your binding in your service

Comment: @KhurramAli: I'm not using a config file. I'm setting the binding entirely within the code (yes, I *know* this isn't the best way to do it, but ...)

Comment: @KenD Set binding something like this  <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" messageEncoding="Mtom"> <!--500MB-->
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1572864"/><!--1.5MB-->
        </binding>

Comment: @KenD:  increase the MaxDepth = 32 to maximum size  , also try to increase receive time out and check it works or not